# Qt resources in GNU makefile

Tags: linux, qt, resources, gnu, qt4.8

How to add Qt resources in GNU makefile?

I want to add something like this:

mystyle.qrc

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>mystyle.qss</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

And it should be used as here:

MyMain.cpp

```
QFile file(":/mystyle.qss");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple rule might look something like...

```
# Specify the `rcc' executable -- `rcc-qt5' on my box but
# may just be `rcc' elsewhere.
#
RCC := rcc-qt5

# Use rcc to generate a .qrc.cpp output file base on the input .qrc
#
%.qrc.cpp: %.qrc
    $(RCC) -name $* -o $@ $<
```

And then just use the generated `.qrc.cpp` as you would any other `.cpp` file.  So if your main source file is `mp_prog.cpp` you could have...

```
my_prog: my_prog.o mystyle.qrc.o
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $+
```

Assuming the usual builtin rules `mystyle.qrc.o` will be built from `mystyle.qrc.cpp` which will, in turn, have been generated from `mystyle.qrc` using the new rule.

Comment: Thanks! Now I have .cpp and .o files. They seems to be good, but it still not working. Is it anything wrong here: QFile file(":/mystyle.qss"); ?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "still not working"?  Are the `.qrc.cpp` and `.qrc.o` files being generated correctly?

Comment: Yes, they are correct... but the file ":/mystyle.qss" still not found.

Comment: I found, that if I add in MyMain.cpp #include <stylesheet.qrc.cpp>, it works. I think it should exist another decision.

Comment: If that fixes the problem then it's almost certainly because you're not linking with the object file created from the generated file `stylesheet.qrc.cpp`.  But without seeing your complete `makefile` it's difficult to tell.